# C: Code below cannot be Compiled?

Tags: c

```
  #include <stdio.h> 

   #define IN   1  /* inside a word */ 
   #define OUT  0  /* outside a word */ 

   /* count lines, words, and characters in input */ 
   main() 
   { 
       int c, nl, nw, nc, state; 

       state = OUT; 
       nl = nw = nc = 0; 
       while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { 
           ++nc; 
           if (c == '\n') 
               ++nl; 
           if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t') 
               state = OUT; 
           else if (state == OUT) { 
               state = IN; 
               ++nw; 
           } 
       } 
       printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc); 
   }
```

I got K&R book but there are some codes that don't compile !

it gives me - 19 C:\Users\Nom\Desktop\Untitled1.c invalid lvalue in assignment

---

edit: now it works, thanks guys, but now it does nothing ! the printf statement doesn't work. It opens the dos console, I type anything and it just return a new line. I'm using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

---

edit: I put the printf statement inside the while loop and it works now. thanks

Comment: perhaps this one should be == " c = '\t'"

Comment: Also `main` should have a return type of `int`.

Comment: Believe it or not, those error messages the compiler gives are there for a reason.  In this case, it mentions an assignment in a line that's not supposed to have an assignment.  So you should probably look at that line to see if there is something that might turn into an assignment if you got it slightly wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')` the last `=` should probably be `==`

Comment: thanks, now it compiles but does nothing ! the printf statement doesn't work. It opens the dos console, I type anything and it just return a new line.

Comment: @heshim: type stuff, then send an EOF. I think that's Ctrl+Z on windows...K&R is very Unix centric.

Comment: You're looping until you enter EOF, which in C is ctrl-d

Comment: @Marc: It's OS-specific, C doesn't say anything about a keyboard.

Comment: I put the printf statement inside the while loop and it works now. thanks

Comment: @heshim Happy coding! Learn lots! :-)

Comment: @heshim: Sticking the printf statement inside the while loop changes the program dramatically. If Ctrl+Z didn't work, try Ctrl+D. That's the normal EOF character on *nix.

Answer (score 2):

```
       if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

you're missing an `=` in the final or clause, should be

```
       if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') 
                                       ^^ here
```

Comment: thanks, now it compiles but does nothing ! the printf statement doesn't work. It opens the dos console, I type anything and it just return a new line.

Comment: If you upvote the accepted answer, consider upvoting this one as well. We came up with essentially the same answer at just about the same time. Fair is fair.